# Is there a Scala "range" method with fractional step size (similar to Python)?

Tags: scala

This works:

```
scala> 0 to 24 by 5
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(0, 5, 10, 15, 20)
```

Negative integer works, too:

```
scala> 0 to 24 by -1
res17: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range()
```

Demands an integer:

```
scala> 0 to 24 by 0.5

<console>:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Double(0.5)
 required: Int
              0 to 24 by 0.5
                         ^
```

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly define a range of `Double`s:

```
scala> 0.0 to 24.0 by 0.5
// res0: scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[Double] = NumericRange(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, ...)
```

A [`Range`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) works with `Int` only. [`NumericRange`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/NumericRange.html) is a more generic version of `Range` that allows one to define a fractional (i.e., of type `Double`) step.